# How to populate data into table onclick button in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I want to populate data into table onclick a button in spring boot. That means I want get data from controller in a button call from a view page. I tried but my request mapping method will not called when I click button.

Here is my code I followed..

1. JSP page button

   ```
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">
       <i class="fas fa-search fa-2x"></i>
   </button>
   ```
2. My table

   ```
    <table class="table">
       <thead>
           <tr>
              <th>LastName</th>
               <th>FirstName</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>

          <tbody>
           <c:forEach items="${userInfoSelectedList}" var="user">
                   <tr>
                       <td>${user.firstname}</td>
                       <td>${user.lastname}</td>

                   </tr>
           </c:forEach>
       </tbody>
   </table>
   ```
3. My Controller Code

   ```
   @Controller
   public class UserRightsController {
      @RequestMapping(value="/user002222", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public String getid(Model model) {      
         List<UserInfoModel> userInfoSelectedList = dao.getUserInfos();
        model.addAttribute("userInfoSelectedList", userInfoSelectedList);
        return "userrights";
       }   
   }
   ```

Problem is that how to call this method onclick button from jsp page.
Please help me..?

Answer (score 0):

You can write call to the web service using JavaScript code in your page:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="callWebService()">
```

Call Web Service in javascript code:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function callWebService() {
        ....
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your GET endpoint in button like:

```
<button onclick="location.href='/user002222'">
```